# Check if subdomain is true or false? javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

Newbie here and I've been trying to write a function that checks if a subdomain is true or false

any guidance is appreciated! and sorry if it's really basic

```
function test(t) {
  if (window.location.hostname === 'news.google.com') {
    return true;
  }
  return t;
}
let x;
console.log(test(x));
```

Comment: It's kinda hard question, cuz you ain't saying true or false relatively to what. What is the kind of problem are you trying to solve? If you want to check is it generally expected site you're on, then this is right. The page and its path you ain't be on, you'll be able to get its hostname and then make your steps. So... More you can read here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp And here's a lot of information about JS too:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: Please provide more details about your question. In this question, we need to know your use case. In your examples, provide meaningful code. you can read more hear https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

So there are 2 ways you could go about this. From your example code we can remove the parameter as it isn't used, `t` in your example is always undefined. We can also just return the result of the equality operator since it will return true / false.

1. If you want to have a static check i.e. always check for the same domain name

```
function test() {
  return window.location.hostname === 'news.google.com'
}
console.log(test());
```

2. If you want to allow the domain name to change

```
function test(domain) {
  return window.location.hostname === domain
}
console.log(test('news.google.com'));
```

Note:

Naming functions is a very important concept so you might want to think of a name that better represents the operation taking place such as `isDomainEqualTo(domain)`